# The markup in the document following the root element must be well

Tags: java, android, sdk

i have try to compalie my android code but i keep getting this error
The markup in the document following the root element must be well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/main_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wwwtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:text="@string/reklama"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/unsel"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/sel" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ing_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/start_game"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have try hard to find an answer but cannot find this
i have root element and i have close all the XML...

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: When I am using the same file, its not giving any error. Tyr to clean or Re-Build the project.